# fast binary digit counter 64bits numbers c#

Tags: c#, performance, binary, counter, ulong

I try to find a solution of this everywhere.
My Request is to find a very fast algorithm code in order to get the number of digits in a binary representation of a unsigned 64bit integrer (ulong).

For example:

```
127 = 7 binary digits.

153 = 8 binary digits.
```

I found by now 2 ways to get this.

- By getting the binary representation trimmed in a string, and use ".Length" property.
- By getting the biggest power of 2 that does NOT pass the number. The result is the very last position of the binary representation, and also indicates the number of digits if you add 1 (that represent 2^0)

Both ways are good, but takes too long to calculate when the number is big. After 10.000.000.000 (10 billions) u have to count the time spent in seconds, instead of miliseconds, and that is so bad for the performance of the rest of the code.

Thanks so much and sorry about the presentation, this is written from a phone and i dont have all the tools to put this fancier and correct.

**EDIT 1**

By taking a deeply look into Bithacks website and having the speed as the first priority. I think I am going to use the [Lookup table](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog) Method with the [**De Bruijn sequence**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence) implementation.

As i found [here](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/De+Bruijn+sequence): the lookup table for 64bits with 2^6 should be something like this.

```
static readonly int[] MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition2 = new int[64]
{
  0,1,2,4,8,17,34,5,11,23,47,31,63,62,61,59,
  55,46,29,58,53,43,22,44,24,49,35,7,15,30,60,57,
  51,38,12,25,50,36,9,18,37,10,21,42,20,41,19,39,
  14,28,56,48,33,3,6,13,27,54,45,26,52,40,16,32
};
```

And based on this, the user "R.." from Stackoverflow, he makes his own [paramether](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3465395/1240074) that in C# should be something like this:

```
public static int GetLog2_DeBruijn(ulong v)
{
return MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition2[(ulong)(v * 0x022fdd63cc95386dull) >> 58];
}
```

The result is really fast but wrong, and i dont know exactly why.
PD: As you can see "0x022fdd63cc95386dull" is for 128bits, the accepted code for C# is "0x022fdd63cc95386d". The same that appear in the lookup tables [here](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/De+Bruijn+sequence).

I think because i cant use the "0x022fdd63cc95386dull" in C#, i have to use another number instead of 58, or maybe a whole different hexadecimal 64bit multiplicator.

By now, for the input number: 17012389719861204799 (64bits used)

- Using pow2 method i get the result 64 1 Million times in 1380ms.
- Using DeBruijn method i get the result 40 1 Million times in 32ms. (Dont know why 40)

Comment: Did you try squaring `2` up to the greatest value smaller than the number you are considering?  Then shift by that digit count (`2^n` digits after `n` squaring steps), and repeat, summing the digit counts along the way.  This should be an order `log log n` process.

Comment: You should show your code - I can't really imagine algorithm of checking at most 64 bits than takes "seconds" to complete...

Comment: Well Alexei, well, yeah, it needs less than a sec, for just 1 operation, but for 10.000 operations for example for the same number it takes 200 times more than 10.000 operations of get number of Digits in decimal, hexadecimal and even the bitcount, all together.

Comment: what about use of bsr asm instruction ? on some CPUs is dasblinkenlight way faster for 32bit but for 64bit should be bsr instruction much faster. still you should check by measurement ... btw hope you 2^n is done by shifting and not by pow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [bit twiddling hack page](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog), you can find the highest bit set like this:

```
uint v;
uint r;
uint shift;

r =     (uint)((v > 0xFFFF) ? 1 : 0) << 4; v >>= (int)r;
shift = (uint)((v > 0xFF  ) ? 1 : 0) << 3; v >>= (int)shift; r |= shift;
shift = (uint)((v > 0xF   ) ? 1 : 0) << 2; v >>= (int)shift; r |= shift;
shift = (uint)((v > 0x3   ) ? 1 : 0) << 1; v >>= (int)shift; r |= shift;
                                        r |= (v >> 1);
// At this point r has the result
```

[Here is a demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/aWaSLY)

Comment: Does this process extend to `ulong` in C#?

Comment: @abiessu Yes, you should be able to extend this to 64 bit.

Comment: It looks good and linear, but the other website said that it takes time for big 64bits numbers, and recommend having a table in memory (if u can). Ill check the code speed tomorrow.

Comment: The DeBruijn sequence algorithm is faster for 32 bits, and can be extended to 64 bits. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10150991/56778

Comment: ive just edited the question, based on Jim Mischel comentary.

Comment: @IgnacioBustos This is not an "edit", it's an entirely different question. You should roll back your edit, and post a separate question [based on R..'s solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3465395/335858). Post a comment to `R..`'s answer to alert him to your new question.

Comment: totally agree, anyway, this was the best answer for my first question.

Answer (score 0):

Try squaring `2` up to the greatest value smaller than the number you are considering.  Then shift by that digit count (`2^n` digits after `n` squaring steps), and repeat, summing the digit counts along the way.  This should be an order `log log n` process.