# How to find the nearest number, that is power of two, to another number?

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm creating a world generator for my 2D game, which uses the Diamond-Square Algorithm in Java, and I've heard that it only works (or at least, only works well) with numbers that are 2<sup>n</sup>+1 (power of two).

The method that generates the world is called with `generateWorld(width, height)`, but that creates a problem. I want to be able to input a `width`, and the function will find the nearest number which **is** a power of two, if the input width isn't. I don't really know how I can do this, so all help is greatly appreciated!

**Summarizing**: If one number isn't power of two, I want to find the nearest number to that one, which **is** a power of two.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to round up to a power of two? Taking the nearest one can make your world smaller than you asked for. A larger one can always be trimmed down in the end.

Comment: Yes, now when you say it, that sounds like a better way. I'll try to use the answers, and round it up. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can round up to a higher power of two (no change if it already was a power of two) like this:

```
x = x - 1;
x |= x >> 1;
x |= x >> 2;
x |= x >> 4;
x |= x >> 8;
x |= x >> 16;
return x + 1;
```

It will give 0 for inputs where the next higher power of two does not exist.

The other candidate is simply half that. Then take the nearest.

Comment: Nice, I missed the fact that we don't actually need to know the log, just the power :) Clean and simple

Comment: Actually, I think this was the easiest one. Also, it was easy to use with `int`s. Thanks!

Comment: How it works? I am unable to get what you are doing here.

Comment: @VikasGupta the shift/or chain in the middle copies the highest set bit to all bits below it. Adding one to it therefore results in the next power of two above the input. To *round* up instead of always going up, one is subtracted in the beginning.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question correctly. 257 results in 512. The nearest power of 2 is 256.

Comment: @Pawel the code snippet is not the answer. The whole answer is the answer, please read all of it. Calculate the other candidate as well, and *then take the nearest*.

Comment: @harold fair enough, I multiplied the initial number by 0.8 instead so more likely to upscale than downscale.

Answer (score 4):

There are two candidates: `2^floor(log2(x))` and `2^ceil(log2(x))`. Just check which of the two is closer.

For integers, you can [use bit fiddling to find the most-significant set bit](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogDeBruijn) to get the exact value of `floor(log2(x))`. I've [written about the idea before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21888140/de-bruijn-algorithm-binary-digit-count-64bits-c-sharp). Again this yields two candidates that you can check.

Comment: `^` is the the bitwise XOR operator in java, and not exponentiation as you might expect.

Comment: @kinbiko Please interpret this answer as mathematical pseudocode, rather than Java

Comment: `ceil(log(x))` rounds up?

Comment: @TheDDestroyer12 yes exactly.

Comment: How can I check if a number is a power of two?

Comment: Also, how can I do it with integers? Eclipse says that `The operator ^ is undefined for the argument type(s) int, double`

Comment: I checked if the number was power of two by using `if((n & (n - 1)) == 1)`, and I used harolds answer, because I thought it was easier to use with `int`s. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @TheDDestroyer12 My suggestion for integers was to find the MSB and then go from there, but as harold demonstrated, getting 2^MSB directly is even simpler, so that's what you should do :) By the way, `^` is exponentiation in math, there is no such operator in Java. You would probably use the `pow` function.

Answer (score 4):

Mathematically speaking, the closest power of 2 would be 2<sup>round(log<sub>2</sub>(x))</sup>.  Java, unfortunately, doesn't have a pre-made method for log<sub>2</sub>, but luckily, it's easily doable with the pre-existing `java.lang.Math` functions:

```
int width = ...;
double log = Math.log(width) / Math.log(2);
long roundLog = Math.round(log);
long powerOfTwo = Math.pow(2, roundLog);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Guava 20+

You have 3 useful methods:

- `IntMath.ceilingPowerOfTwo(x)`
- `IntMath.floorPowerOfTwo(x)`
- `IntMath.isPowerOfTwo(x)`

and you can check which one of the floor power of 2 and the ceiling power of 2 is closer.

**E.g.:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for ( int i = 1 ; i < 13 ; i++ ) {
        nearestPowerOfTwo(i);
    }
}

private static void nearestPowerOfTwo(int x) {
    int ceil = IntMath.ceilingPowerOfTwo(x);
    int floor = IntMath.floorPowerOfTwo(x);
    System.out.print(x + " ---> ");
    if ( IntMath.isPowerOfTwo(x) ) {
        System.out.println(x + " (the number is power of 2)");
    } else if ( ceil - x > x - floor ) {
        System.out.println(floor);
    } else if (ceil - x == x - floor) {
        System.out.println(floor + " and " + ceil);
    } else {
        System.out.println(ceil);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 ---> 1 (the number is power of 2)
2 ---> 2 (the number is power of 2)
3 ---> 2 and 4
4 ---> 4 (the number is power of 2)
5 ---> 4
6 ---> 4 and 8
7 ---> 8
8 ---> 8 (the number is power of 2)
9 ---> 8
10 ---> 8
11 ---> 8
12 ---> 8 and 16
```

There are also `LongMath` and `DoubleMath` if the `IntMath` is not enough.